# Split parentheses using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like this: `R3(a1b1,a1c1,b2c1),` or `R3(a1b1,a1c1,b2c1).`
I want to split it into two arrays `[R3]` and `[a1b1,a1c1,b2c1]`.
I tried some naive ways such as `String line1[] = line.replaceAll("\\(", ",").replaceAll("\\)", "").replaceAll("\\.", "").split(",");` to split the string into an array and then split the array but it doesn't work.

Comment: "it doesn't work." Can you be more specific? What was the error?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. The error comes from another code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regexs should be

```
String rx1 = "[()]";
String rx2 = ",";
```